# The jcarousel module does not display image field

Tags: javascript

I created a block through views page. The display format is jcarousel, the seclected field is image from a specific content type. It shows the empty field with an icon instead of images. If i add other fields like title... it is showing but only with image fields it has problem. The conteny type as well have many contents with images and texts.

Comment: What happens when you visit the url of the image that is regenerated? Has the file been previously uploaded to the site? If you are using `image styles` are you sure the `directory permissions` are OK for your `files` directory to allow Drupal to create scaled images. All these things topics can be found by using Google.

Comment: yes you just go for inspect elements and check the image path.

Comment: Should i check image path in my content type image field? and as well i don't know how to check directory permissions. sorry but i am not fully familiar with.